# JQuery File Upload preview File Type to allow all file types

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to preview different file types, but Its not working. By default jQuery File upload only previews Image files(jpeg | png | gif). But I need to display a preview for Other File types such as (pdf | doc | pptx | txt). How to achive this??
I tried changing this, but no luck

Existing Code:

```
previewFileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/,
```

My Change: (Still does not show preview for pdf, doc, ppt)

```
previewFileTypes: /^.*\/(gif|jpeg|png|pdf|PDF|pptx|plain|doc|docx)$/,
```

Answer (score 1):

The preview is for showing images. The PDF and document file types are not images, and cannot be shown. From the [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/README.md):

> Preview images, audio and video: A preview of image, audio and video
>   files can be displayed before uploading with browsers supporting the
>   required APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Is there anyway we could preview other file type??

Comment: Not without first uploading it to the server, and then creating an image thumbnail. The other document types don't have any sort of access to a thumbnail image, which is what the preview is.