# File Upload with Preview for Image and Non-image File Types

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, amazon-s3

I've done a lot of poking around on the net and SO to try to find a solution to my problem. So far, no luck.

I want a file uploader on my site that will generate thumbnail preview images of a user's uploaded file (they are restricted to uploading one at a time) for any of the allowable file types (like jpg, gif, Word, pdf, and more).

I did find this: [JQuery File Upload preview File Type to allow all file types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002688/jquery-file-upload-preview-file-type-to-allow-all-file-types), which states that what I want to do is not possible unless the file is first uploaded to the server and then a thumbnail is generated for the file. I am totally cool with that, but don't know where to start in building that!

I am looking for a solution that will play nice with Bootstrap + PHP + AWS S3, but can be flexible. It could be a paid or free solution, but I'd rather not pay hundreds a month for it (or even tens of dollars a month!)

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I know I *should* be posting a code sample, but I don't have one to post at this point! As you can tell, I am rather new to this file upload thing, so you if you want to talk to me like I am five that might be appreciated! lol

Comment: if you dont care IE 9 or below there should be a lot of options and plugins around

Comment: "Word" , "pdf" not image files ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856729/upload-multiple-image-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/

Comment: You're obviously better at Interneting than me, @guest271314! I'll play around with this.

Comment: Oh, you're the author! I read that wrong. Nice. So the image shown once uploaded is a preview of the file? (Viewing the image with a right-click loads the resource, so I am just curious.) This might be the solution I need...